# Out of the box Light Switch HTML app has a null error in IE9?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I am trying LightSwitch for the first time, and after making a new HTML C# App - I tried to run it just to see what it looks like.  IE9 freezes immediately and I get this error from Visual Studio 2013:

`Unhandled exception at line 5, column 19701 in http://localhost:49609/HTMLClient/Scripts/msls-2.5.1.min.js`

`0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'cultures': object is null or undefined`

Does anyone know whats going on?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue - I am running Lightswitch in an offline environment and these two scripts were 404'ing:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js

Once saved in the solution I loaded fine.

Answer (score 0):

This impacted me on VS 2015 all browsers. I think this is because of a closed environment for the server.

Lin M is basically correct:
Download the two files into the Scripts folder:
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js

Next:
In **default.htm**  change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/globalize.min.js"></script>
```